# I need to insert a captcha for all comments in word press

Tags: plugins

Hi I am new to word press. I need to insert captcha for all the comments wherever seen in word press theme. How can I do it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

With this plugin you can do it.
http://wordpress.org/plugins/captcha/